# Do items downgrade when repaired after being damaged?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

In Divinity: Original Sin, if an item's durability goes down to 0 and then the item is repaired, is it as good as new or does it become worse (and if so, to what extent)?

Comment: The other question asks about the repair system in general, while here I'm specifically interested in what happens when durability gets down to 0. I don't think that's a duplicate.

Comment: True the questions are slightly different but the answer there does cover what you're looking for when it addresses if there are any downsides, mentioning that it _used_ to lower maximum durability but no longer does.

Comment: I'd agree with Virus that it does cover your point. Perhaps the other question could add on to be a little more specific to cover what else you're wondering. But generally it's as they said, it becomes good as new, it used to reduce max durability.